# I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) for below code.Please help me out

Tags: c, pointers

```
void SortedInsert(struct node** headRef, struct node* newnode)
{
        struct node* current= *headRef;

        if(newnode->data<current->data)
        {
                newnode->next=current;
                *headRef=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
                current=current->next;                  
                while(current!=NULL)
                {

                        if(newnode->data<current->next->data)
                                break;

                current=current->next;
                }

                newnode->next=current->next;
                current->next=newnode;
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please provide a __[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)__

Comment: Also, you can use a debugger like `gdb` to step through your program and pinpoint the offending instruction.

Comment: Think about what values `current` could possibly have *after* you have looped `while(current!=NULL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when you insert at the end of the list. Then you get

```
// current = NULL
current->next = nextnode;
// is ((struct node*)NULL)->next = nextnode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not sufficient to point out the error.

However, as a general suggestion, there are a lot of pointer dereference without the validity (`NULL`) check. Please add a check to see if the pointer is valid or not before dereferencing the same, as `NULL` is considered invalid value of a pointer and trying to dereference that produces  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This will lead to segmentation fault, at times.